# Yesod, withAsync

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, yesod

I'm a newbie to Haskell & Yesod and I'm trying to use the `Control.Concurrent.Async` module to do stuff async. (the code is based on: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:withAsync)

```
quizWidget = do
   --Get first question   
    withAsync (showQuizItem 1 1 ) $ \qi -> do
    withAsync (showScoreboard)    $ \sb -> do

    quizItem <- wait (qi)
    scoreboard <- wait (sb)

    toWidget $(hamletFile "hamlet/quiz.hamlet")
```

But this produces the following error:

> "No instance for (MonadWidget IO) arising from a use of ‘toWidget’".

So the question is what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The API in the async package is *monomorphic*, meaning it works only for actions in `IO`. You're trying to use it in the `WidgetT` transformer type instead, which is where the error message is coming from. You can use the [lifted-async](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.3/lifted-async-0.9.1.1/Control-Concurrent-Async-Lifted.html) package, which provides a polymorphic variant of the `withAsync` function. For the most part, this should just be a matter of:

1. Import `Control.Concurrent.Async.Lifted`
2. Add `lifted-async` to your `build-depends`